# Length of sequences of numbers greater than x in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I need to **retrieve the length of sequences, which numbers are all greater than an arbitrary chosen value `x`** (some kind of "severity").

A sequence can be for example:

```
list = [4, 3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 7, 6 ]
```

In this case, a scenario could be:

```
x=6
[1, 3] # since there are only two sequences with values greater than 6 (the 6 alone, and the triplet 6,7,6]
```

The question is similar to: [Python: determine length of sequence of equal items in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964963/python-determine-length-of-sequence-of-equal-items-in-list) , which works only for sequences of equals numbers.

For this reason, in my 'draft' I start from the maximum number of a list (in the previous scenario `x=7`) and afterwards replace it with a lower one and find the length of these sequences (replacing all 7 with 6 and run the same algorithm to find length of sequences of at least 6).

Which is the pythonic way to do it without a plain loop?

Comment: a plain and simple `for` loop should not be too hard to code. have you tried that?

Comment: So did you try *adapting* that code for your purposes? You shouldn't just expect it to be handed to you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't want the code, I want to know if there exist a better way to struct the algorithm. I have solved the problem by starting from the maximum severity and decreasing by one unit iteratively the max, so that I get the right number of patterns lengths. 
Do you want me to post this? As I told is inspired from the similar problem of finding lengths of patterns with same unique value

Comment: @Ev.Kounis probably I should add I am doing this for around 2000 files, so I would still rather prefer the non for loop option. But yes, you are right. I was wondering if there is a way to use groupby in this fashion but I don't think

Comment: Then it's not clear to me what you're asking. Are you trying to determine the appropriate value of x? On what basis?

Comment: No, I am willing to retrieve given an arbitrary x value: _the lengths of all patterns which exist which satisfy the condition for a pattern which is that all elements of a pattern are greater than x_. 

Should I update something, which part you find misleading?

Comment: Then yes, you can adapt the `groupby` usage in the other question. That method does *not* work only for sequences of equal numbers, that's just the specific problem they've applied it to; you need to change the condition, and add some filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative method using groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [4, 3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 7, 6 ]
x = 6

out = [len(list(group)) for larger, group in groupby(elem >= x for elem in data) if larger]
```

This method works by grouping values according to the boolean comparison `elem >= x`, and then recording the lengths of the groups in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [4, 3, 4, 5, 2, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 7, 6 ]
x = 6

out = [sum(1 for _ in group) for is_larger, group in groupby(data, lambda value: value>=x) if is_larger]
print(out)
#[1, 3]
```

`groupby` groups values according to the condition `value >= x`, which becomes the key `is_larger`.

We only keep the groups where `is_larger` is `True`, and for these ones, we get their length with `sum(1 for _ in group)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this, to make the steps more readable. Maybe not the most elegant solution, but only needs basic list comprehension and string functions.

```
list = [0 if el < 6 else el for el in list]
str = ''.join(str(el) for el in list)
sequences = [seq for seq in str.split('0') if seq is not '']
lengths = [len(seq) for seq in sequences]
```

Comment: It's an artifact like mine of replacing iteratively maximum numbers, but thanks, I'll test which is the most efficient

Comment: I think for an efficient implementation you should consider using numpy.